# decode a base 64 encoded string using ATL Base64Encode with ATL_BASE64_FLAG_NOPAD flag

Tags: c++, base64, atl

how to decode a base 64 encoded string encoded using Base64Encode with ATL_BASE64_FLAG_NOPAD flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that just means "don't put the `=` at the end" you can add the padding directly:

```
public static string Base64PadEnd(string unpadded)
{
    switch(unpadded.Length % 4)
    {
        case 0: return unpadded;
        case 2: return unpadded + "==";
        case 3: return unpadded + "=";
        default: throw new ArgumentException("Invalid unpadded base64");
    }
}
```

(The way base64 works, you should never end up with an unpadded value with a final block of 1 character.)

After adding the padding, just use `Convert.FromBase64String` as usual.

EDIT: As noted in comments, if your base64 string contains whitespace, you should remove that first *before* adding the padding. A simple `text = Regex.Replace(text, @"\s", "")` should do the trick.

Comment: +1. Side note: Base64 allows whitespaces  to be part of Base64 string, so simple length may not be enough unless you are sure it was encoded with "ATL_BASE64_FLAG_NOCRLF" flag or you verified that string contains only Base64 character.